# set permission for a file, only executable, not readable, without permission to copy

Tags: linux

In linux, is it possible to make all files in a directory only executable, with no permission to copy and read? whould be great if somebody tell me which one is the case:

for example:
`(rwxr-xr-x)` The file's owner may read, write, and execute the file. All others may read and execute the file

read by others means they can copy or not?
Is this means what I want: only executable not read, not copy ==> 751

Comment: What do you mean by copy, copy in or copy out?

Comment: somebody copy files in this directory to his directory

Comment: If you can read a file, then you can copy its contents. You cannot (logically!) disallow copying while allowing read access.

Comment: SO, rwxr-x--x : somebody can execute files from your directory but no permission to copy out, correct?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a binary (not a directly executable shell script) you can change permissions to `711`

```
chmod 711 a.out
```

will make the binary executable but not readable.

This will not work with shell scripts because the shell interpreter would need to have read permissions in order to read the script's contents before executing them.

---

It's obvious that you'll need read permissions for a copy operation. Having `711` permissions nobody except of the owner (and the kernel) can read, and therefore copy the file.

Comment: it's perl program, is it ok?

Comment: rwxr-x--x, can do what I want?

Comment: No, I told that and told why. Btw, why not just trying it?